# Как открыть информацию о приложении?

Tags: java, android

Зная имя пакета, хочу открыть информацию о приложении в настройках(где можно остановить приложение, стереть данные, удалить и т.п.).
Как создать интент, что бы открылась информация о приложении?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18873867/3212712) надо так:

```
packageName = "your.package.name.here"

try {
    //Open the specific App Info page:
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
    startActivity(intent);

} catch ( ActivityNotFoundException e ) {
    //e.printStackTrace();

    //Open the generic Apps page:
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

---

Ответ по первой ссылке гугла на запрос:

> [android app info intent](https://www.google.ru/search?q=android%20app%20info%20intent&oq=android%20app%20info%20intent&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.6759j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)